# get FileSystems of a jar inside another jar

Tags: java, jar, java-8

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
FileSystem fs1 = FileSystems.newFileSystem(Paths.get("f1.jar"), null);
FileSystem fs2 = FileSystems.newFileSystem(fs1.getPath("/f2.jar"), null);
```

but I get a `java.nio.file.ProviderNotFoundException` thrown by `FileSystems.newFileSystem()` on the second line.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: So... both Java 7 and Java 8? Which one are you actually using?

Comment: @bcsb1001 forgot to remove the tag, fixed

Comment: Trying to open the zip file system directly using `new ZipFileSystemProvider().newFileSystem(` *path inside another zip* `, emptyMap())` you will get an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [have to](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2265518?start=0&tstart=0) extract nested jar first.

Edit:
Answers on oracle forum don't give clear reason why you have to extract jar first.

Here is quote [from](https://blogs.oracle.com/rajendrag/entry/zip_file_system_provider) Rajendra Gutupalli's blog (author of com.sun.nio.zipfs):

> Let's assume that we have a Jar file nested inside a Zip. The following program prints the contents of the MANIFEST.MF file which is inside nested jarCompress1.jar file.
>
> ```
> import java.io.BufferedInputStream; 
> import java.nio.file.*; 
> import java.util.HashMap; 
> import java.util.Map;
>
> public class ReadEntry {
>
>     public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
>         Path zipfile = Path.get("c:/zips/zip1.zip");
>         Map<String, String> env = new HashMap();
>         FileSystem manager = FileSystems.newFileSystem(zipfile, env,null);
>         Path path = manager.getPath("/jarCompress1.jar/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
>         System.out.println("Reading input stream");
>         BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(path.newInputStream());
>         int ch = -1;
>         while ((ch = bis.read()) != -1) {
>             System.out.print((char) ch);
>         }
>     } 
> }
> ```

And another [one](https://blogs.oracle.com/rajendrag/entry/zip_file_system_provider_implementation):

> Important point to note here is, zip file path can expand to nested zips or jars in the file's path name. For example, /home/userA/zipfile.zip/DirA/dirB/jarFile.jar/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF accesses the jar file “jarFile.jar” inside Zip file “/home/userA/zipfile.zip”.

I couldn't reproduce claimed behavior. Next code:

```
try (FileSystem fs1 = FileSystems.newFileSystem(Paths.get("f1.zip"), null)) {
    Path path = fs1.getPath("/f2.zip/test.txt");
    Files.lines(path).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Gives exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: f2.zip/test.txt
  at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.newInputStream(ZipFileSystem.java:544)
  at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipPath.newInputStream(ZipPath.java:645)
  at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.newInputStream(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:278)
  at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:152)
  at java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedReader(Files.java:2781)
  at java.nio.file.Files.lines(Files.java:3741)
  at java.nio.file.Files.lines(Files.java:3782)
```

May be someone would confirm that it's a bug or point to the error in my code.

Meanwhile returning to your original question. You cannot create FileSystem inside zip(jar) because there is no `FileSystemProvider` (look source code of `newFileSystem` method) which can create `FileSystem` instance from ZipPath. Hence you have to options extract the from outer zip or write your own `FileSystemProvider` implementation.

Comment: Please summarize the content of the link in your answer. If the link goes dead, this answer will not be helpful.

Comment: The blog you are referring to is way out-of-date. It was written years before Java 7 came out and is wrong regarding several issues, e.g. the Scheme is `Jar` rather than `Zip` and the zipfs is not read-only. So it’s like the blog is describing an entirely different software…

Comment: Firstly `ZipFileSystemProvider` extends `FileSystemProvider` which `@since 1.7`. Secondly look at stages dates of [JSR203](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=203). Thirdly zip and jar essentially the same.

Answer (score 0):

Given a jarfile URI like: jar:file:/console/console.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/generator.jar!/generator/static/

I wrote the following method to extract the jars recursively and return all of the file systems:

```
private FileSystem getNestedFileSystems(URI generatorAssets) throws IOException {
    String[] jarFiles = generatorAssets.toString().split("!");
    URI rootJarUri = URI.create(jarFiles[0]);
    FileSystem currentFs;
    try {
        currentFs = FileSystems.getFileSystem(rootJarUri);
    } catch (FileSystemNotFoundException fsnf) {
        currentFs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(rootJarUri, Map.of("create", "true"));
    }
    Path currentJar = null;
    if (jarFiles.length > 2) {
        for (int i = 1; i < (jarFiles.length - 1); i++) {
            Path nestedJar = currentFs.getPath(jarFiles[i]);
            Path extractedJar = Files.createTempFile("jar-" + i, ".jar");
            Files.copy(nestedJar, extractedJar, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            currentFs.close();
            if (currentJar != null) {
                Files.delete(currentJar);
            }
            currentJar = extractedJar;
            currentFs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(URI.create("jar:file:" + extractedJar),
                    Map.of("create", "true"));
        }
    }
    return currentFs;
}
```

Returning a list of filesystems so you can close them all after use and not leak FD's. The last FileSystem will be able to get your desired directory/object/etc

Comment: You copy the file contents. The OP wants to access the file in a nested JAR without extracting it (using only FileSystem API).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved at least in Java 14 (maybe earlier). OP's code works there with one change: you need to add an explicit cast to `ClassLoader` for the second argument of `newFileSystem`.

For a more complete example, this code prints the contents of `README.md` which is inside the `internal.zip` archive which itself is inside the `archive.zip` archive:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path zipfile = Paths.get("archive.zip");
        FileSystem manager = FileSystems.newFileSystem(zipfile, (ClassLoader) null);
        Path internal = manager.getPath("internal.zip");
        FileSystem internalManager = FileSystems.newFileSystem(internal, (ClassLoader) null);
        Path internalFile = internalManager.getPath("README.md");
        Files.lines(internalFile).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Note that file names inside archives are case-sensitive.