# Read and Modify content of inner zip file using ZipInputStream

Tags: java, file, zip, zipinputstream

I am trying to modify web.xml using ZipInputStream. File to read is web.xml which is inside ear/war file

**C:/XX.ear/YY.war/WEB-INF/web.xml**

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("C:/XX.ear");
    Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();
    while(entries.hasMoreElements()){
        ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
        if(entry.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("YY.war")){
            ZipInputStream inputStream = new ZipInputStream(zipFile.getInputStream(entry));
            ZipEntry zipEntry;
            while(( zipEntry  = inputStream.getNextEntry())!=null)
            {
                System.out.println(zipEntry.getName());// Prints WEB-INF/web.xml
                if (zipEntry.getName().endsWith(".xml")) {
                    ZipInputStream iStream = new ZipInputStream(zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntry)); 
                      // throws NullPointerException here

                }                   
            }                   
        }                       
    }
```

new ZipInputStream(**zipFile**.getInputStream(zipEntry)) I couldn't point to inner zip file to get input stream of inner war file

Is it possible to read the inner zipentry as inputstream ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Java 7 nio2 package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html) has a new file system interface and a new [Zip File System provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html).  The interface and provider allow to [traverse the zip tree in a visitor pattern style](https://blogs.oracle.com/xuemingshen/entry/the_zip_filesystem_provider_in1) This should provide a more clear and efficient way to get to the inner zip file

Edit: I tried to traverse a zip-inside-zip and got an exception. according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26219534/get-filesystems-of-a-jar-inside-another-jar), you have to extract the inner zip in order to traverse it.